# Wordpress - Woocommerce: where this links are added?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

scenario:
I'm trying to add a query string to the add-to-cart-wrapper in my search at the bottom of every product page.

So far I've successfully done it for the button, but not for all the other links present into the add-to-cart-wrapper div.

you can see what I mean at the very bottom of this page:
[Demo page to see the problem](http://lnx.metalstyle.eu/wp/prodotto/recinzione-in-ferro-classica/?product_cat=recinzioni&orderby=date)

There are two links that I cannot find in the code: one added under

```
<div class="product-header">
```

and one under

```
<div class="add-to-cart-wrapper">
```

I don't know where they are added and wheter it is by php or JS.
Anyone can help pointing me in the right direction?

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Here for reference the last part of content-product.php with my little modification.

```
<li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>
<?php 
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
?>
    <div class="product-header">
        <?php



            echo '<div class="add-to-cart-wrapper">';
            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
                sprintf( '<a href="%s?%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="btn btn-md %s product_type_%s">%s</a>',
                    esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
                    esc_html($myargs["query"]),
                    esc_attr( $product->id ),
                    esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
                    $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
                    esc_attr( $product->product_type ),
                    esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
                ),
            $product );
            echo '</div>';
        ?>
    </div>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); echo ("?".$myargs["query"]); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>

    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_rating - 5
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' );
    ?>



<?php

    /**
     * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );

    ?>
```

Comment: I don't get it, I see 2 links, one at: apply_filters and another at <a href="<?php the_permalink(); e

Comment: Yes Skatox, those are the two links set "explicitly", but on the final page, there are a lot more, clearly set elsewere, and that's what I'm asking... I cannot find where they are set. I suspect they are added using jQuery...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you're having issues with links inside other links, the problem like your theme says:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item' ); ?>
<?php 
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
             * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title' );
```

In this section it will do those actions which any other plugin or the theme itself calls and injects custom code, in this case, your links. Search for those hooks and remove them to avoid any link injection.

Comment: Thanks Skatox, I know how hooks works, but my main problem is that I cannot find where those hooks are called in order to add them: between woocommerce, theme and plugins there is a lot of intertwined calls! 
Anyway, because I'm running out of time with this, I've chosen to do it the dirty way: manipulating the page with jQuery.
Unfortunately I have no time to look further into that now.

Comment: well, if this worked you can select it as the answer. Btw, what I do is to search for the hook name and chek the calls, then copy the same call but with remove_action at the functions.php so I can delete it.